# impl vs derive in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust. I've found this code in Rust's compiler.

```
#[must_use]
pub struct IeeeFloat<S> {
    /// Absolute significand value (including the integer bit).
    sig: [Limb; 1],

    /// The signed unbiased exponent of the value.
    exp: ExpInt,

    /// What kind of floating point number this is.
    category: Category,

    /// Sign bit of the number.
    sign: bool,

    marker: PhantomData<S>,
}
```

Then they did

```
impl<S> Copy for IeeeFloat<S> {}
impl<S> Clone for IeeeFloat<S> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}
```

My question is, isn't this same as #[derive(Copy, Clone)]? Why do they explicitly write *impl Copy for IEEE*? And isn't this clone implementation the same as the clone in std? Why would you redefine it

Link [is here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8064a495086c2e63c0ef77e8e82fe3b9b5dc535f/compiler/rustc_apfloat/src/ieee.rs#L146)

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not the same as deriving because the compiler won't make it generic enough. When you have a generic type `T<U>`, and try deriving `Clone` for it, it will only implement `Clone for T<U>` for `U: Clone`, **even if `T<U>` could be cloned without having `U: Clone`**. Note that it is the case for `IeeeFloat<S>`, since `PhantomData<S>: Clone` for all `S`.

Comment: Then why do you think they explicitly write the clone function? And the definition seems the same in the std

Comment: @merovingian to remove the need of the bound `S: Clone` for clone and `S: Copy` for Copy